# Create Model Vs Reverse engineer model in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

What is difference between Create Model and Reverse Engineer Model in Entity Framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reverse engineering you start with an existing database and generate your model.

With create model, you start by defining your model, and then get EF to generate a database script.

Comment: where create model is used ?